# as3 declaring a GLOBAL variable - in TIMELINE / outside of CLASS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scope, global-variables, global

I am looking to declare a GLOBAL VAR in the main time line.

Then I need to access that GLOBAL VAR from another externally loaded SWF's.

**QUESTIONS:**

How do I create the global var in the main timeline?

How do I access that var in externally loaded swf files?

Comment: -1 for no other reason than the fact that there is always a better solution than using a global. Globals in any OOP language is just a shame.

Comment: AS3 is not just OOP, and globals certainly do have a place -- for example `Event` names.  No reason for negs on bad design ideas . . . that's what comments are for, after all.

Comment: AS3 is not just OOP. Okay... please feel free to expand on that one? What is it, a procedural language? *Crosses eyes and makes a retarded face*. Anyway it's a far cry between having some standard defined types for a highly specific type of a class design and, as the OP says, slapping a global variable out there in the global namespace so that any loaded content can access it from anywhere. You really want to justify global.myVar with a comparison to Class.CLASS_TYPE???

Comment: I agree with Ascenscion that users should NOT be encouraged to use global/static state (http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/), but downvoting someone's question pretty much guarantees they'll take the first answer someone gives that's the opposite position of the down voter's, without truly considering the finer points involved.

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't use **any** [global/static state](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/). In your situation this is even **more** true, because Singletons are a royal pain in the butt across different applicationDomains.

Instead, you should use something called [Dependency Injection](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html). Think of your little swfs as starving orphans. When they have loaded, they don't run up to your main swf and pick its pockets. Instead, the main swf magnanimously presses money into their little hands.

So, how do we make this happen? One way is that we could compile a reference to their Document class(es) into the main swf, and then we could set a variable that the Class exposes. However, this can get pretty heavy and isn't really necessary.

Instead, you can write something called an [Interface](http://www.developria.com/2009/10/interfaces-and-dynamic-class-i.html), which defines the "idea" of an orphan.

It might look something like this:

```
public interface IOrphan {
   function get alms():Number;
   function set alms(value:Number):void;
}
```

Note that you have to use getters and setters with Interfaces, because you can't use them to define vanilla variables.  However, that's going to work out great for our actual Orphan:

```
public class Oliver implements IOrphan {
    private var _alms:Number;
    private var _totalAlms:Number;
    public var tf:TextField;//put this on stage and allow Flash to populate automatically
    public function get alms():Number {
       return _alms;
    }
    public function set alms (value:Number):void {
      _alms = value;
      _totalAlms += _alms;
      updateAlmsMessage();
    }
    private function updateAlmsMessage():void {
       tf.text = 'That was a donation of ' + _alms + '.\n'
                 'I now have ' _totalAlms + '.\n'
                 'Please, sir, can I have some more?';
    }
}
```

Now, all you need to do is populate that variable on load. There are several ways you can do this, such as [watching the stage](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html) for IOlivers to be loaded, or you could be more direct about it:

```
private function loadSwf(url:String):void {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            loader.load(request);
            addChild(loader);
}

private function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
   ((e.target as LoaderInfo).content as IOrphan).alms = .25;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are variables that you only want to set once and will never change, you can just create a class that holds static constants.

```
package
{
    public class Env
    {
        public static const WHATEVER:String = "Whatever!";

        public function Env()
        {}
    }
}
```

Then you could access them later in your program like so:

```
trace(Env.WHATEVER);
```

However, if you want global variables that can change, I like to handle this by using a singleton class.

```
package 
{
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

public class Control extends EventDispatcher
{
    //---------------------------------------
    // PRIVATE & PROTECTED INSTANCE VARIABLES
    //---------------------------------------

    private static var _instance:Control;

    //---------------------------------------
    // PUBLIC VARIABLES
    //---------------------------------------

    public var whatever:String = "Whatever";

    //---------------------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    //---------------------------------------

    public static function get instance():Control
    {   
        return initialize();
    }

    public static function initialize():Control
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new Control();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    //---------------------------------------

    public function Control()
    {
        super();
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            throw new Error("Error:Control already initialised.");
        }
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }

}
}
```

The difference here is that you need to grab the instance of your singleton before you can get to what's inside it. It'd look a little bit like this.

```
private var _control:Control = Control.instance;
// Reading a global variable
trace(_control.whatever);
// Change a global variable
_control.whatever = "Foobar!";
```

So whenever you change "whatever", that variable will change for all loaded SWFs. If you want to be really fancy about it, you could use getters/setters in your singleton rather than simple public variables.